# ngLocal nomod error

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I'm currently building a meanjs (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) application. When I run my app with grunt locally, it works great. However, when I deploy to digital ocean or heroku I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Object
```

This is obviously not a very helpful error on angular's part. However I was able to set a break point to gain more information on the error message. (See this http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/).

Here was the error message:

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available!
```

I found that the error I was getting was that ngLocale was not available. What? This is included in angular.... how could it not be available?

Even more strangely, everything loads and works fine locally. I've tried to be a detective about it, but I haven't been able to figure out anything concrete. I can't figure out for the life of me why this default module isn't loading. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Angular will try to load 'ngLocale' module first and if it's not exists, the default one will be created. A strange thing in your case is that there is a try/catch already why it still show as an uncaught exception. See the source code: (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/AngularPublic.js#L143)

Comment: May be the `Uncaught Object` isn't actually related to the `ngLocale`. It come from somewhere else.